# In Observable: how to get button click to call a function

Tags: observablehq

I am generating a list of lines with "html" library function. I put a button on each line and want it to call a function when clicked. I tried:

```
html`<div>Line text <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button></div>`
```

`myFunction` is defined in the notebook but it doesn't get called when the button is clicked. My use has dozens of lines in the "html" not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this new template library made by Observable  [htl - Hypertext Literal](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/htl)

Template

```
    html`<button onclick=${() => ++mutable clicks}>click me</button>`
```

Mutable or your function

```js
    mutable clicks = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched more and found [this notebook](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/views-are-mutable-values) by Mike Bostock which answers the question indirectly in an example. What I need to do is:

```
{
  const form = html`<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Line text <button name="myButton">Click</button></div>
  </form>`;
  form.myButton.onclick = () => {
    // put the button click code here
  };
  return form;
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For buttons created as [`inputs`](https://github.com/observablehq/inputs/blob/main/README.md#button) components, the function just needs to be put into the `reducer` option

```
viewof myButton = Inputs.button(
  "Button Label Text",
  { reduce: myFunction }
)
```